# SSIS: printing ssrs report

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

There is a package with script task which prints SSRS report. Package runs and everything is just perfect. When I deploy it to production server it doesn't work and I know it's because of the printer I'm sending it to (it's invalid, it's not on the list).

The problem is... SQL Server Agent service account has printers configured, not to mention the printer I'm sending this report to is set as default.

The package is run by another account which has printers configured, correct permissions (for testing purposes this account can do pretty much anything), the fuzzy stuff.

The account running SSIS, in the other hand, can do very little (not even fancy kerberos passing :).

Any suggestions? If you could just point me in the right direction, it would be great.

**EDIT**
Package runs from SSIS, but doesn't run from SQL Server Agent. We are trying to ad-hoc fix the bug in another companys software (it doesn't create few reports, users don't want to use it, people walking backwards, cats living with dogs), waiting for patch. We can't change the code for obvious reasons, the only solution is to find reports which are not created and create them on our own.

Comment: Back in the days when people road dinosaurs to work, we'd simply pipe the contents of a file to lpt1 `type myfile.txt > lpt1` The first obstacle to overcome is the default printer. Either you need to establish the correct printer for the right account or when you call the print operation, you will need to provide everything it needs (path to device, I assume). Perhaps you're over complicating matters and instead establish subscriptions for SSRS the deliver to a printer (at least I think that's possible)

Comment: Thank you for your response, billinkc. It is possible I'm over complicating. Package runs from SSIS, but doesn't run from SQL Server Agent. I don't want to create windows service because It's tiresome (server admin might try to reboot machine and forget to check if services started, too annoying)